# How to generate a Monero wallet programatically?

Tags: wallet

I want to generate both the `monerowallet` and `monerowallet.keys` files, but I can't find any resources on how to do it. The cli tools offer a `--generate-new-wallet`, but it requires manual overhead and user input. Is there any good way to do this?

---

Update:

Using `monero-python` I can generate all the keys, but even using the monero-wallet-cli's `--generate-from-json` it still prompts for user input so I can't do it that way either.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it requires manual overhead"? What's your use-case?

Comment: `--generate-from-json` doesn't prompt for input if all the required parameters are in the json file. Also, you don't need to pre-generate any keys, just a seed. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, just:

```
monero-wallet-cli  --create-address-file --password password123 --mnemonic-language English --generate-new-wallet ./new.wallet
```

You can enumerate new.wallet with a variable.  Just wait a few seconds and (p)kill the client before moving on to next.

Comment: In addition to my answer, this works too.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options.

One option is to have a running wallet RPC: `monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-dir . --rpc-bind-port 18085 --disable-rpc-login`

Which you can then call its [create_wallet](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet) method like:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:18085/json_rpc -d \
  '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"create_wallet","params":\
  {"filename":"monerowallet","password":"pass","language":"English"}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Another option would be to use `monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-json wallet.json` when you have a `wallet.json` with content like:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "filename": "monerowallet",
  "scan_from_height": 1796000,
  "password": "pass",
  "seed": "some valid seed ..."
}
```

But of course that requires you to have already created a seed.

Lastly, another approach I've seen used is to create a wrapper script around `monero-wallet-cli --generate-new-wallet` which uses redirection to echo input to the `monero-wallet-cli` processes stdin. There are many ways to accomplish this and is very much shell specific.

The RPC method is probably your best option (without knowing your use-case).